# Warning (2): mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

Tags: php

Hi i recently faced this problem but was able to fix it. Actually spelling mistake in path. I  want to know how to handle these error properly. i.e my program should continue executing and should safely return a false  if mkdir fails. This is my code

```
try
{
    foreach($folders as $folder)
    {
        $path  = $path.'/'.$folder;    
        if(!file_exists($path))
        {
            if(!(mkdir($path)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
catch (Exception $e){
    return false;
}
```

I just want if mkdir is not able to create it. It should return a false and the execution should continue

**EDIT**: Here is updated code based on community feedback. But still no proper answer to my question

```
if(!file_exists($newfolder))
 {
    if(mkdir($newfolder,0755,true))
    {
                return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What's with the try-catch? Nothing here could possibly throw an exception.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for [setting the `recursive` flag to `true`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)?

```
<?php
// Desired folder structure
$structure = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
// to mkdir() must be specified.

if (!mkdir($structure, 0, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

// ...
?>
```

Comment: i justed edited it. I have no prolem if mkdir falis but execution should continue it has to return a false –

Answer (score 1):

The function appears to not be recursive. You will have to make the entire directory tree, down to your directory that you want to create.
Read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#80549). Like sarnold said, just set the recursive argument to true.

Comment: i justed edited it. I have no prolem if mkdir falis but execution should continue it has to return a false

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this sample, it might be what you are looking for.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#92844